# No Wear OS Virtual Device for Android 13 (API 34) in Android Studio's Device Manager

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os, android-virtual-device, android-wear-2.0

In Android Studio's Device Manager, I'm unable to find a virtual device option for Wear OS with Android 13 (API 34). While I've noticed options for Android 13 for phone devices in the "Virtual Device Configuration", there seems to be none for Wear OS.

Interestingly, I've encountered users in production with Samsung Galaxy Watch 6 devices running Android 13. This makes me wonder why there isn't an emulator version available for it.

Has anyone been able to emulate Android 13 for Wear OS in Android Studio? If so, how?

Details:

- Android Studio Version: 2022.3.1 (Giraffe)
- Target SDK: 34 Android API
- 34 SDK: Updated to the latest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Wear OS 4 image is available in the canary channel, so you can either:

1. Download Android Studio [preview release](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview) (currently Hedgehog) and it will be available in the Device Manager (more detailed instructions [here](https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/versions/4/setup#download-install-emulator)):
   [image]
2. Install via command line using [sdkmanager](https://developer.android.com/tools/sdkmanager) so it can be used in the stable version of Android Studio (currently Giraffe):

   - Download the Android SDK Command line tools
     [image]
   - Run the command `sdkmanager "system-images;android-33;android-wear;arm64-v8a" --channel=3`, once it's done, it should be available in the Device Manager.